# PyParsing Different String Lengths

Tags: python, parsing, firewall, rules, pyparsing

I'm writing a parser for firewall configuration file.
I am new to PyParsing and Python in general.

The question is how do i parse if more then 3 arguments occur, (xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) != (xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx), All rules are working fine and parse everything correctly if each line contain no more that 3 strings, but we can see that [Firewall [F1]] contains "NAT" after address field, and is ignored no matter how we change the rule.

Using (def printTokens(s,loc,toks):   #s=orig string, loc=location, toks=matched tokens)

Please see the 2 outputs when using 4th argument ("NAT") and when we erase it.
Thanks in advance!Need to parse everything including "NAT" with rules implemented.

```
from pyparsing import *

#===================================GRAMMER==================================
zone = Literal("zone")    
zoneid = Word(alphanums)
host = Literal("host")
hostid = Word(alphanums)
interface = Literal("interface")
interfaceid = Word(alphanums)
firewall = Literal("firewall")
firewallid = Word(alphanums)
router = Literal("router")
routerid = Word(alphanums)

fstop = Literal(".")
comma = Suppress(",") #Converter for ignoring the results of a parsed expression.
slash = Literal("/")
ocbracket = Literal("{")
ccbracket = Literal("}")
sobracket = Literal("[")
scbracket = Literal("]")
hyphen = Literal("-")
underline = Literal("_") 
word = Word(alphas)


#===================================IP-TYPE=================================

ip=Combine(Word(nums)+            
        fstop+ Word(nums) + 
        fstop+ Word(nums) + 
        fstop + Word(nums))

subnet = Combine(slash +Word(nums))

address = ip + Optional(subnet)


#===================================RULES===================================

#adword = address + word

zoneRule = zone + zoneid + address
hostRule = host + hostid + ocbracket
interfaceRule = interface + interfaceid + address 
interfaceRule2 = interface + interfaceid + address + word
firewallRule = firewall + firewallid + ocbracket
routerRule = router + routerid + ocbracket

endRule = ccbracket


rule = zoneRule | hostRule | interfaceRule | interfaceRule2 | firewallRule | routerRule | endRule 
rules = OneOrMore(rule)

#===================================DATA=====================================
details = """zone zone1 10.1.0.0/24                   
         zone backbone 10.254.0.0/24
         zone zone 10.2.0.0/24
         host ha {
             interface iha 10.1.0.1
         }
         host hb {
            interface ihb 10.2.0.1
         }
         firewall f1 {
            interface ifla 10.1.0.254 
            interface iflback 10.254.0.101 nat
         }
         router r2 {
            interface ir2back 10.254.0.102
         }
         router r3 {
            interface ir3b 10.2.0.103
         }"""

#==================================METHODS==================================

    def printTokens(s,loc,toks):   #s=orig string, loc=location, toks=matched tokens
    print (toks)

zoneRule.setParseAction(printTokens) 
hostRule.setParseAction(printTokens)
interfaceRule.setParseAction(printTokens)
interfaceRule2.setParseAction(printTokens) #takes in 4 instances where as 3 declared
firewallRule.setParseAction(printTokens)
routerRule.setParseAction(printTokens)
endRule.setParseAction(printTokens)

rules.parseString(details)


#================================OUTPUT RESULT WITH NAT=================================
"""
['zone', 'zone1', '10.1.0.0', '/24']
['zone', 'backbone', '10.254.0.0', '/24']
['zone', 'zone', '10.2.0.0', '/24']
['host', 'ha', '{']
['interface', 'iha', '10.1.0.1']        
['}']
['host', 'hb', '{']
['interface', 'ihb', '10.2.0.1']
['}']
['firewall', 'f1', '{']
['interface', 'ifla', '10.1.0.254']
['interface', 'iflback', '10.254.0.101']"""
#================================OUTPUT RESULT WITHOUT NAT=================================
"""['zone', 'zone1', '10.1.0.0', '/24']
['zone', 'backbone', '10.254.0.0', '/24']
['zone', 'zone', '10.2.0.0', '/24']
['host', 'ha', '{']
['interface', 'iha', '10.1.0.1']
['}']
['host', 'hb', '{']
['interface', 'ihb', '10.2.0.1']
['}']
['firewall', 'f1', '{']
['interface', 'ifla', '10.1.0.254']
['interface', 'iflback', '10.254.0.101']
['}']
['router', 'r2', '{']
['interface', 'ir2back', '10.254.0.102']
['}']
['router', 'r3', '{']
['interface', 'ir3b', '10.2.0.103']
['}']"""
```

Comment: Try reordering `rule = zoneRule | hostRule | interfaceRule | interfaceRule2 | firewallRule | routerRule | endRule` to `rule = zoneRule | hostRule | interfaceRule2 | interfaceRule | firewallRule | routerRule | endRule`. Also, try making `interface2` more specific, if possible, like `interfaceRule2 = interface + interfaceid + address + CaselessLiteral('nat')` or `interfaceRule2 = interface + interfaceid + address + oneOf("nat ext ipv6 other1 other2")`. Also look at the 2.1.5 release, including `pyparsing_common` definitions for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match any number of expressions with a certain delimiter, use [PyParsing's delimitedList](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/delimitedList.html). By default it allows whitespace around the delimiters; add `combine=True` to require no whitespace.

However, if you want to allow optional items in your grammar, you should just add an optional item. For your interface rules, you can replace:

```
interfaceRule = interface + interfaceid + address 
interfaceRule2 = interface + interfaceid + address + word
```

With:

```
interfaceRule = interface + interfaceid + address + Optional(word)
```

Finally, the actual issue with the code you posted is that you are using the `|` operator, which is a short-hand form for [MatchFirst](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/class-MatchFirst.html). MatchFirst will try the given options *in order*, and return the result of the *first* one which matches. If you use [Or](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/class-Or.html) instead, for which the short-hand form is the `^` operator, then it will instead try *all* of the options and return the one with the *longest* match.

Comment: `Optional` is a good suggestion for this problem, but may need to be more specific than just `word` since that matches any word-group of alphas, which could include the leading `interface` of the next firewall rule.

Comment: Thank you very much for number of solutions, have tried them all and re-ordering  rules does its job, in fact using Optional(word) as per comment above is replaced with word "interface" so using ClasslessLiteral('nat') is one way of solving. The only problem will be if i ever bump into more than 'nat' ill manually will have to add those Literals. But the question is answered . Thank you very much . Appriciated your help !